# Me gustaría / quisiera / querría

Tags: uso-de-palabras

I usually use "*me gustaría*" when asking for something or expressing myself towards something I would like to do. How about "*quisiera*" and "*querría*" can both be used the same way and what are the differences between them?

> Me gustaría vivir en Hawaii.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to think of it in two ways.

> Me gustaria vivir en Hawaii

I would see more as, the prospect/thought of living in Hawaii is pleasing to me.
Whereas something like *quisiera* I would use in different contexts. I think of it like the past subjunctive tense of querer, meaning something that could be possible but perhaps in more of an active sense.

For example if I wanted to express the english for, 'I would have liked you to tell me how things were' 
I probably wouldn't say "*me hubiera gustado si me hubieras dicho como fueran las cosas*" (plus it doesn't sound right) I would say:

> quisiera que me dijeras las cosas tal cual 
>   I wanted you to tell me things as they are.

It feels more active.

Because in present tense I would say

> Quiero que me digas las cosas

I'm not sure there is much difference but I have always felt *quisiera* to be more of an active word or question. 
Also I rarely hear people say, *te gustaría ir al cine? o quisieras tomar un cafe?* as we might say in English, *would you like this or that*. Mostly people just ask "*¿quieres?*" and not whether or not it would *please* you.

> Si quisiera vivir en Francia, ¿vivirías conmigo?

(If I wanted to live in France would you live with me?)

Hope this helps, and lets see what natives have to say

Comment: @Andaluci You're welcome. Spanish is a really fun language and full of great nuances :)

Comment: Claro, pero es fácil ;) muchas gracias por todo Adam :) more questions to come! He terminado nivel uno curso, pues tengo que practicar y hablar con la gente :)

Answer (score 2):

I think there are a few minor differences between them:

- `Me gustaría` is more of a long term wish, that can only be satisfied over time, maybe a few years.  Por ejemplo, `Me gustaría ser doctor cuando sea grande` would be an example of something a kid would say.
- `Quisiera` is more of an immediate wish.  You're expressing a desire, that you'd like to satisfy immediately or in the near future.  In this context `Quisiera ser doctor` would be more like "I wish I was a doctor" (implying right now), instead of "I want to become a doctor" (in the future sometime).
- `Querría` has a very similar meaning to `me gustaría`, but is used much less often (at least in normal, colloquial spoken Spanish).  In my opinion, it sounds a bit too formal, but I think it's a matter of preference.

Comment: Both answers are informative. I use `me gustaría` when I want to call someone on the phone in a formal way. Por ejemplo `me gustarîa hablar con José` rather than using `quiero hablar con María` OR `puedo hablar con Jesus`.